# Discord бот не добавляет пользователей в бд

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Я пишу discord бота (discord.py) на python, в котором будет рейтинговая система. Когда пользователь присоединяется к серверу, бот должен автоматически записывать его в бд (sqlite3), а если я отмечаю его сообщения реакцией (например ✅), бот должен прибавлять пользователю 500 очков в бд. Но когда я со 2 аккаунта присоединяюсь к серверу, бот не добавляет меня в бд, при вызове команды /top не отображает меня в списке пользователей, а команда /points выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Ignoring exception in command points:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\main.py", line 75, in points
    xp = cursor.execute(f"""SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}""").fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Вот код:

```
import re
import sqlite3

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
from config import settings

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=discord.Intents.default())

connect = sqlite3.connect("server.dp")
cursor = connect.cursor()


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(bot)
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        points INT
    )""")
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0)")
            else:
                pass
    connect.commit()
    print("Bot connected!")


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id from users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0)")
        connect.commit()


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
    if payload.member.id == bot.user.id:
        pass
    elif payload.member.id == 633717285474795557 and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET points = points + 500 WHERE id = {payload.member.id}")
        connect.commit()


@bot.command()
async def points(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member:
        xp = cursor.execute(f"""SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}""").fetchone()[0]
        await ctx.send(f"У пользователя **{member.mention} {xp}XP**")
    else:
        xp = cursor.execute(f"""SELECT points FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}""").fetchone()[0]
        await ctx.send(f"У вас **{xp}XP**")


@bot.command()
async def top(ctx):
    users = []
    user_xp = list(cursor.execute(f"SELECT points FROM users").fetchall())
    top_users = {}
    for user in [user for user in list(cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM users").fetchall())]:
        users.append(re.sub("[)|(,']", "", str(user)))
    top_users = dict(zip(users, user_xp))
    sorted_values = sorted(top_users.values())
    sorted_top_users = {}
    for val in sorted_values:
        for key in top_users.keys():
            if top_users[key] == val:
                sorted_top_users[key] = top_users[key]
                break
    top_str = ""
    counter = 0
    for name, xp in sorted(list(sorted_top_users.items())):
        counter += 1
        top_str += f"{counter} - {name}: {list(xp)[0]}XP\n"
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Топ участников по колличеству XP:", colour=discord.Colour.green(),
                        description=f"**{top_str}**")
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)

bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно ваше событие `on_member_join` не срабатывает из-за того, что у Вас `intents=discord.Intents.default()`. Потому что (выдержка из документации)

> A factory method that creates a :class:`Intents`
> with everything enabled except :attr:`presences` and :attr:`members`.

> [`Intents.presences`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.presences)
>
> Whether guild presence related events are enabled.
>
> This corresponds to the following events:
>
> - on_member_update() (activities, status)
>
> This also corresponds to the
> following attributes and classes in terms of cache:
>
> - Member.activities
> - Member.status
> - Member.raw_status

> [`Intents.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.members)
> Whether guild member related events are enabled.
>
> This corresponds to the following events:
>
> - on_member_join()
> - on_member_remove()
> - on_member_update() (nickname, roles)
> - on_user_update()
>
> This also corresponds to the following
> attributes and classes in terms of cache:
>
> - Client.get_all_members()
> - Guild.chunk()
> - Guild.fetch_members()
> - Guild.get_member()
> - Guild.members
> - Member.roles
> - Member.nick
> - Member.premium_since
> - User.name User.avatar (User.avatar_url and User.avatar_url_as())
> - User.discriminator

Это означает, что события просто не вызывается!

В документации в разделе `A Primer to Gateway Intents` решение Вашей проблемы описано: [ссылка](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go)

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Причина в том, что забыли добавить `connect.commit()`:

```
for guild in bot.guilds:
for member in guild.members:
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0)")
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Сравните id (или имена) авторов сообщения. Они будут разные.  Один это бот, второй это пользователь.

В данном случае надо просто создавать пользователя если его нет.

В функции points ветвление идет по пути else и пытается получить пользователя по id которого нет в БД. .fetchone() вернет None у которого при попытке получить что либо по индексу возникнет TypeError.